# Find a Coefficient of an expansion

Tags: number-theory

I have given expression $(X+X^a+X^b+X^c+X^d+....)^k$ where $a$, $b$, $c$ ... and $k$ are whole numbers.

How we can find the $Z$ coefficient, i.e, $X^Z$ of the above term $1\le Z \le k$?

For Example $(X+X^3+X^5+X^8)^4$. How can I find the $X^{13}$ coefficient.

Comment: See if this is helpful:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product

Comment: I get $12X^{13}$ in the example, by counting.

Comment: [Contest problem](https://www.codechef.com/MAY16/problems/CHEFMATH)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps there is some kind of answer using generating functions, but I don't know enough about that.

What I would do is, just as for a binomial expansion:

$$(a + b)^{n} = \sum_{k = 0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}a^{k}b^{n-k}$$

there is also this formula to sum $m$ terms (from wikipedia here, multinomial theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem):

$$(x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3} + ... + x_{m})^{n} = \sum_{k_{1} + k_{2} + ... + k_{m} = n}^{n}\binom{n}{k_{1},k_{2},...k_{m}}\prod_{1\leq t \leq m}x_{t}^{k_{t}}$$

with

$$ \binom{n}{k_{1},k_{2},...k_{m}} = \frac{n!}{k_{1}!k_{2}!...k_{m}!}$$

Of course, expanding this for a concrete case, such the next you are mentioning needs to be done very carefully.

Answer (score 0):

You have the following powers of $X$ available to you: $1, 3, 5, 8$.

You need to combine four of these to make $13$. How can this be achieved?

$8+3+1+1 = 13$

$3+3+3+1=13$

Can it be done any other ways?

In your example each of these contributes a total of $1 \times 1 \times 1 \times 1 = 1$ (note that in general this will be something more complicated if the $X^k$ had a coefficient other than $1$), so the overall coefficient is the sum of these (for how many you have).